# I can't find what's wrong with my markdown LaTex code (\begin{align} ~ \end{align})

Tags: latex, markdown

First of all, I need to let you know I'm completely ignorant of LaTex.

I guess it's a very simple problem for those who know well.

But for me, even simply searching about this is very difficult. So I post a question here.

Anyway here's the thing.

```
>$$
>\begin{align}
>    &\text{minimize}\_{x \in D} &{f(x)} \\\\
>    &\text{subject to } &{g_{i}(x) \leq 0, i = 1, \dotsc, m} \\\\
>    & &{h_{j}(x) = 0, j = 1, \dotsc, r}, \\\\
>\end{align}
>$$
>
>where $f$ and $g_i, i = 1, \dotsc, m$are all convex,$h_j, j = 1, \dotsc, r$are all affine, and the optimization domain is${D = {\rm dom}(f) \cap \bigcap\_{i=1}^m {\rm dom}(g_i) \cap  \bigcap\_{j=1}^r {\rm dom}(h_j)}$.
```

It supposed to look like this :

[image]

However, what I've got is like this:

[image: I used VSC as my markdown editor]

Could you tell me what's wrong with my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your markdown uses latex and not, say, mathjax?

Comment: Off-topic: You are missing a lot of spaces around your inline math expressions

Comment: [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) has nothing whatsoever to do with LaTeX, but some implementations to add support for rendering LaTeX from Markdown. What tool are you using to process your Markdown?